# Routing of symlinked files via NFS

Tags: nfs

I have several disk servers (call them A, B, ...) exporting NFS shares. To simplify the access to data I created a folder in an NFS share on another machine (call it Z) with symlinks to all the NFS shares on the various servers, so that my compute nodes can refer to a single folder to access all the files. But I don't know what happens when multiple nodes access to multiple files on different servers through the symlinks in Z. Will all the data be routed through Z? Or after resolving the symlink will every node connect directly to its related disk sever? If the former case is what actually happens then I'll have to find out another way since I can't live with the resulting bottleneck. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resolving client will follow the path and will directly access the other nfs server. No proxying is happening. IOW, in your case if server Z has a pointer to server A, then client will connect access server Z only to read the content of the link and then directly talk to server A.